# Tap to click keeps disabling

Tags: snow-leopard, macbook-pro, trackpad

Recently the tap to click on my trackpad will disable itself after a restart and I have to go into System Preferences to enable it. Has anyone experienced this and know of a solution?

I'm running Snow Leopard on a white MacBook (Mid 2010).

Comment: It probably won't help, but you could try deleting `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch.trackpad.plist`. Missing preference files are recreated automatically, so that should be harmless.

Answer (score 1):

Open Terminal.app and enter the following to (re-)enable tap to click on the Trackpad:

```
defaults write com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch.trackpad Clicking -bool true
```

Then, log out and log back in again.